# For Loop result doesn't make sense to me

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

So I had the following code snippet on a quiz:

```
int a = 120;
int b = 90;
int n1 = Math.abs(a);
int n2 = Math.abs(b);
int result = 1;

for (int k = 1; k <= n1 && k <= n2; k++) 
{
   if (n1 % k == 0 && n2 % k == 0) 
   {
      result = k;
   }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

The output is 30 and I'm not sure why. As far as I can see, wouldn't the loop keep running until the counter broke 90 (90 being the absolute value of n2)? That would make result = 90. Or is there just something I'm not quite understanding?

Answer (score 2):

If you printed out `k` when it is set to `result`, you'd see it print out the common factors of `n1` and `n2`.

90 doesn't evenly divide both `n1` and `n2`.

30 does

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH I feel dumb now, thanks man, that makes sense, so, essentially, it keeps going until it reaches the highest factor of both number that isn't greater than either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that your `if`-statement checks so that `k` divides both `n1` *and* `n2`. 90 does not divide 120.

Answer (score 0):

Since 30 is the greatest common factor of 120 and 90 (30 is the greatest number that both 120 and 90 are evenly divisible by), any number above 30 will cause the if statement to evaluate to false, so result will be 30 for the remainder of the program. Hope this helps!